# Trying to iterate over several levels of nested arrays keep getting 'does not have any construct or call signatures'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component I'm working on where I need to iterate over several arrays at various sub levels to print out contact details in a table.

The two sections I need to iterate over are phone numbers and addresses and they are nested like so:

```
const contacts = {
  count: 1,
  groups: [
    {
      contactGroup: 'Family',
      count: 1,
      contacts: [
        {
          name: 'BENJAMIN BUTTON',
          email: 'ben@buttons.com',
          phoneNumbers: [
            {
              telephone: '(123) 456-7890',
              type: 'Work'
            },
            {
              telephone: '(999) 555-9999',
              type: 'Cell'
            }
          ],
          addresses: [
            {
              addressLine1: '123 FICTION ST',
              addressLine2: 'APT  1208',
              city: 'SAN DIEGO',
              state: 'CA',
              zipCode: '12345'
            },
            {
              addressLine1: '456 DREARY LN',
              addressLine2: '',
              city: 'SEATTLE',
              state: 'WA',
              zipCode: '67890'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In my function below I'm trying to access and iterate over that section but I'm running into issues because when I go to iterate over it I get the error 'does not have any construct or call signatures'.

I think it might be because I'm trying to run another for loop midway through my previous one but I'm not sure and I can't seem to figure out a way around that error to print out all the information to the table

```
  const rows = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < contacts.groups.length; i++) {
    rows.push(
      <tr>
        <td>{contacts.groups[i].contactGroup}</td>
      </tr>
    );
    for (let j = 0; j < contacts.groups[i].contacts.length; j++) {
      rows.push(
        <tr>
          <td>{contacts.groups[i].contacts[j].name}</td>
// This is the line where I get the error
          {for (let x = 0; x < contacts.contactGroups[i].contacts[j].length;x++){

          }}
          <td>{contacts.contactGroups[i].contacts[j].email}</td>
          {/* <td>{contacts.contactGroups[i].contacts[j].addresses}</td> */}
        </tr>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSX, stuff in curly braces must be an expression - it cannot be a statement (like your for loop).

Expressions are evaluated then yield a value. Statement do not.

You could make it an expression like so:

```
contacts.contactGroups[i].contacts[j].map(item => (<div>{item}</div>))
```

As a side comment - it's the first time I see for loops like this in React code, and they are all simply iterating on all the array items. This is pretty much always done using `map`, sometime chained to `filter`.

Comment: Yeah the reason I was using for loops is because the actual number of contacts I'm getting back is a lot, so I thought that might be the best way to iterate over each contact inside the array and print out their details

Comment: I tried to implement that expression but unfortunately now I'm getting a TypeScript error stating the object is possibly null

Comment: Could you share the line on which it complains?

Comment: Yeup it's ```<td>{contacts.contactGroups[i].contacts[j].phoneNumbers.map(item => (<div>{item}</div>))}</td>```

Comment: Not sure, but I doubt it's coming from `map` - it always returns an array.